# XSLT File Not working in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to transform my Legacy Service Response into CDM Service Response. For that i am using XSLT Mediator in WSO2 ESB. I am confused about the syntax of my XSLT.That i am doing it right way or not? 
XSLT mediator works fine. I have confirmed it. 
I am trying it on an online tool first http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php.

**Legacy Response(Input):**

```
<GetPersonResponse xmlns="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001">
   <Person xsi:type="ns1:Person" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns2:PersonId xmlns:ns2="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">4224</ns2:PersonId>
      <ns3:FirstName xmlns:ns3="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">John</ns3:FirstName>
      <ns4:LastName xmlns:ns4="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Doe</ns4:LastName>
      <ns5:FatherName xmlns:ns5="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Khalid</ns5:FatherName>
      <ns6:Religion xmlns:ns6="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Islam</ns6:Religion>
      <ns7:MotherTongue xmlns:ns7="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Urrdu</ns7:MotherTongue>
      <ns8:DateOfBirth xmlns:ns8="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">1893-02-02</ns8:DateOfBirth>
      <ns9:Gender xmlns:ns9="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:GenderType">Male</ns9:Gender>
      <ns10:CurrentAddress xmlns:ns10="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns10:AddressDetailId>194</ns10:AddressDetailId>
         <ns10:StreetNo>5</ns10:StreetNo>
         <ns10:HouseNo>123</ns10:HouseNo>
         <ns10:Town>Johar</ns10:Town>
         <ns10:District>Lahore</ns10:District>
         <ns10:City>Lahore</ns10:City>
         <ns10:State>Punjab</ns10:State>
         <ns10:Country>Pakistan</ns10:Country>
         <ns10:Postal>54000</ns10:Postal>
      </ns10:CurrentAddress>
      <ns11:HomeAddress xmlns:ns11="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:AddressDetail">
         <ns11:AddressDetailId>195</ns11:AddressDetailId>
         <ns11:StreetNo>5</ns11:StreetNo>
         <ns11:HouseNo>123</ns11:HouseNo>
         <ns11:Town>Johar</ns11:Town>
         <ns11:District>Lahore</ns11:District>
         <ns11:City>Lahore</ns11:City>
         <ns11:State>Punjab</ns11:State>
         <ns11:Country>Pakistan</ns11:Country>
         <ns11:Postal>54000</ns11:Postal>
      </ns11:HomeAddress>
      <ns12:Height xmlns:ns12="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">6</ns12:Height>
      <ns13:Weight xmlns:ns13="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">100</ns13:Weight>
      <ns14:CNIC xmlns:ns14="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">35302</ns14:CNIC>
      <ns15:ContactInfo xmlns:ns15="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01" xsi:type="ns1:ContactDetail">
         <ns15:HomePhone>454545</ns15:HomePhone>
         <ns15:CellPhone>3343434</ns15:CellPhone>
         <ns15:WorkPlacePhone>34343434</ns15:WorkPlacePhone>
         <ns15:Email>omer@gmail.com</ns15:Email>
      </ns15:ContactInfo>
      <ns16:MaritalStatus xmlns:ns16="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Single</ns16:MaritalStatus>
      <ns17:Nationality xmlns:ns17="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">Pakistani</ns17:Nationality>
   </Person>
   <ResponseCode>PERSON MODULE SUCCESS - 00</ResponseCode>
   <ResponseMessage>Data Fetched Successfully</ResponseMessage>
</GetPersonResponse>
```

**What Should be the Output:**

I want to just change the value of "Religon" element and replace it's value with "FatherName" element value. Rest of Response should remain same.

**My XSLT:**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:m0="http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//m0:GetPersonResponse">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//m0:Religion"/>
    </xsl:template>                     

    <xsl:template match="//m0:Religion">
    <xsl:value-of select="//m0:FatherName"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried it by removing the namespaces but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace of **GetPersonResponse** is `http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01_RequestResponse_001`
Must must specify THIS namespace, not remove it or use m0 which refer to "http://com.example.com/xsd/Person_01"

However, m0 is the right namespace for **Religion** node